# Not possible to set Preferred domain after setting change of address in GWT

Tags: google-search-console

I have been struggling with GWT for the past few weeks. I used to have an old personal website whose main address was `example.com`. I developed a new one at a different host, using `example.cc`. I want `.cc` to be my new main domain from now on, so I forwarded `example.com` and `example2.com` (another domain which used to point to `example.com`) to `example.cc`.

Following the instructions from GWT, I added 6 properties:

- `example.cc`
- `www.example.cc`
- `example.com`
- `www.example.com`
- `example2.com`
- `www.example2.com`

The verification was correct and the forwarding seemed to work perfectly. However, I cannot set the preferred domain option in `example.cc` anymore. I have been waiting for a few weeks, but still the option seems disabled. All the transfers of address (`www.example.com`, `example.com`, `example2.com`, `www.example2.com`) have been submitted and successful according to GWT:

> Your request for a site move has succeeded.
>   If you believe this is an error, you can withdraw the request.

Any thoughts on what can I be doing wrong? I have been checking posts with similar questions, but to the best of my knowledge the configuration was different.

Comment: I've [exemplified your domain(s)](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/example-domain-cleanup), however, the last domain in your list was a duplicate - I assumed this was just a typo in your question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the "preferred domain" only relates to the `www` canonicalisation of `example.cc`. But if you've already set up canonical 301 redirects to the preferred domain then you don't need to set the preferred domain in GSC (formerly GWT).

Comment: Thanks @w3dk for exemplifying, I was not aware of that. And yes, that was a typo!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, there is no need to make canonical the redirections between them? This is how I understood the process should be done, I might not be understanding it correctly:

- Preferred domain example.com with respect to www.example.com
- Preferred domain example2.com with respect to www.example2.com
- Preferred domain example.cc with respect to www.example.cc
- Set 301 from example.com, www.example.com, example2.com, www.example2.com, www.example.cc to example.cc

Comment: In addition, I have noticed while searching on google that some old entries (from www.example.com) are still there. Is this issue related to this? I did the transfer of domain around 3 weeks ago. Thanks!

Comment: "no need to make canonical the redirections between them?" - well, you primarily do that through your 301 redirects (and maybe `rel="canonical"` tags). You can use the "Change of Address" tool in GSC but that's it AFAIK. It would seem to be pointless to set the "preferred domain" (ie. www or non-www) for `example.com` and `example2.com` if _all_ traffic from these domains are being redirected to `example.cc`. It can take some time for the old URLs to be updated - Googlebot needs to recrawl these URLs to see the redirect. Although you would expect a "Change of Address" to be relatively speedy?

Comment: "I cannot set the preferred domain option in `example.cc` anymore" - I'm not sure why that is. Is the option simply disabled? Maybe that is related to the "Change of Address" tool - if you have already specified the target to be `example.cc`, rather than `www.example.cc`. (Or are you expecting to see `example.com` and `example2.com` in the list? That isn't going to happen, since the "preferred domain" option only relates to the www and non-www variants. The "preferred domain" option in GSC is of primary importance to users who are unable to configure 301 redirects on their site.)

Comment: Hi @w3dk! > It would seem to be pointless to set the "preferred domain" (ie. www or non-www) for example.com and example2.com if all traffic from these domains are being redirected to example.cc

OK, thanks for clarifying this... really helpful!

Comment: > Is the option simply disabled? 

There is not even option, the following message is displayed: "Not all options are available because of a Change of Address request related to this site."